# Unity - Combining data increases RAM usage -> Garbage Collector causes frame drops

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory, garbage-collection

Right now, I'm working on a QuadTree LOD system for planets. In general everything is working quite nice.

[image: My planet with QuadTree LOD]

As a rough description of how the mesh is generated:
Every node generated by the QuadTree contains a container called "NodeMeshData". This contains all information to generate a simple Mesh

```
public class NodeMeshData
{
    public Vector3[] vertices;
    public int[] indices;
    public Vector2[] uvs;

    public void Clear()
    {
        vertices = null;
        indices = null;
        uvs = null;
    }
}
```

Whenever the mesh needs to be regenerated, all QuadTree nodes without any children (leaf nodes) are asked for there NodeMeshData. All these are put into one Array of NodeMeshData objects.

```
public void UpdateQuadTree(Vector3 playerPosition)
{
    _quadTree.UpdateTree(playerPosition);

    NodeMeshData[] data = _quadTree.GetNodeMeshData().ToArray();
    CombinedMeshData.Combine(data);
}
```

(CombinedMeshData is a NodeMeshData property from the class where this method is)

The problem now lies in the combining of all these NodeMeshData objects into one to generate the final mesh - the extention method "Combine". By process of elimination I found out that it must be this method that causes the problem I have.

```
public static class NodeMeshHelper
{
    public static void Combine(this NodeMeshData newData, IList<NodeMeshData> nodeMeshData)
    {
        int verticesCount = nodeMeshData.Sum(static nmd => nmd.vertices.Length);
        int indicesCount = nodeMeshData.Sum(static nmd => nmd.indices.Length);
        int uvsCount = nodeMeshData.Sum(static nmd => nmd.uvs.Length);

        List<Vector3> vertices = new(verticesCount);
        List<int> indices = new(indicesCount);
        List<Vector2> uvs = new(uvsCount);

        int lastIndex = 0;

        foreach (var meshData in nodeMeshData)
        {
            vertices.AddRange(meshData.vertices);

            int[] shiftedIndices = meshData.indices.Select(index => index + lastIndex).ToArray();
            lastIndex += meshData.indices.Last() + 1;
            
            indices.AddRange(shiftedIndices);
            uvs.AddRange(meshData.uvs);
        }

        newData.vertices = vertices.ToArray();
        newData.indices = indices.ToArray();
        newData.uvs = uvs.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Whenever it is called and executed, the RAM usage rises. After a few seconds, the garbage collector kicks in and cleans the memory of all the unused data as it is supposed to do. But this results in a nasty frame drop every single time.

[image: Screenshot from the Unity Profiler]

My idea is that all these declarations of new Lists or the AddRange calls cause the rising RAM usage. From asking my collegues I found out, that declaring Lists with a fixed size should eliminate the internal redeclarations of Arrays within the List objects when AddRange is called. But as you can see, I already do that and it doesn't help. I also tried to change the NodeMeshHelper into a non static class with fields for the lists or the final NodeMeshData result. It didn't help either.

What can I do to fix this? Is there a simple way, e.g. changing the "Combine" method in a way that it doesn't use new memory every single time? Or do I need to rethink my QuadTree or mesh creation algorithm completely (I hope not)? What about compute shaders?

Whoever is interested in the full code:
[Github](https://github.com/BanditBloodwyn/Paleozoic/tree/master/Assets/_Project/_Scripts)

**UPDATE**

I changed the NodeMeshHelper to not longer use Lists. Now it uses Arrays. I did that because it seems to improve the performance a bit. Also I hope that it might go in the right direction to fix my major problem. Yes, I know there still are "new" statements for the arrays.

```
public static class NodeMeshHelper
{
    public static void Combine(this NodeMeshData newData, NodeMeshData[] nodeMeshData)
    {
        int vertexIterator = 0;
        int indexIterator = 0;
        int uvIterator = 0;

        int verticesCount = 0;
        foreach (var nmd in nodeMeshData) 
            verticesCount += nmd.vertices.Length;

        int indicesCount = 0;
        foreach (var nmd in nodeMeshData) 
            indicesCount += nmd.indices.Length;

        int uvsCount = 0;
        foreach (var nmd in nodeMeshData) 
            uvsCount += nmd.uvs.Length;

        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[verticesCount];
        int[] indices = new int[indicesCount];
        Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[uvsCount];

        int lastIndex = 0;

        foreach (var meshData in nodeMeshData)
        {
            // vertices
            foreach (Vector3 vertex in meshData.vertices)
            {
                vertices[vertexIterator] = vertex;
                vertexIterator++;
            }

            // indices
            foreach (int index in meshData.indices)
            {
                indices[indexIterator] = index + lastIndex;
                indexIterator++;
            }
            lastIndex += meshData.indices[^1] + 1;

            // uvs
            foreach (Vector2 uv in meshData.uvs)
            {
                uvs[uvIterator] = uv;
                uvIterator++;
            }
        }

        newData.vertices = vertices;
        newData.indices = indices;
        newData.uvs = uvs;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I also tried to implement this in Unitys Job System. But unfortunately it does not support NativeArrays of NativeArrays, which (in my brain) is necessary for my purposes.

Comment: Consider not using LINQ in a _game._ User code is so far removed from the final code (especially when it all depends on what is on the other end of LINQ) that you have no idea what it is producing.  Most of the time LINQ is just sugar syntax that good ol' `foreach` can easily replicate. The _Rx_ framework is notorious for its junk objects it creates.

Comment: Good point. But it didn't help here. But I will leave these changes in my code because you're right anyway, so thanks :)

Comment: The thing you really should be doing is try to allocate all large objects _once_, say at the start of a level.  For you this means allocating all the memory you need for your mesh once and rather than allocate new lists on the fly simply _re-use_ what you already have. Gregory, J, _["Game Engine Architecture"](https://www.amazon.com/Engine-Architecture-Third-Jason-Gregory/dp/1138035459)_, 2022.  And yeah, ditch LINQ.

Comment: Reusing what I have is exactly what I already thought to do. That's why I have a NodeMeshData property in the class where "UpdateQuadTree" is implemented. So this NodeMeshData object should be reused all the time. How can I reuse the stuff in the "Combine" method? I don't know in advance how large the data is that needs to be combined so the containers need to be dynamic (e.g. Lists). Am I wrong with this?

Comment: _"I don't know in advance how large the data is"_ - you're still thinking about it wrong.  That only applies if you are allocating the data/buffers _multiple_ times per game session which isn't what I'm proposing.  Perform whatever operation you need to do to create the buffers and the _"size"_ will pop out the other end.  What changes though is that when you need to refresh the data because the space ship is now lower to the planet's surface, you now ensure that it fits the previously allocated buffers.  Once you allocate these large buffers, you want to **avoid** `new` like the plague. :)

Comment: ....I highly recommend the above-linked book.  It goes into it in detail.

Comment: Your combine method makes new lists every time and then will need gc on them.  So yes until you change that  you will always allocate and deallocate

Comment: Sorry, I know what you all are talking about, but I don't know what to do now. I tried Arrays as fields in a non static "NodeMeshHelper" class (huge arrays, because I don't know how many vertices I will have to merge). But that crashes everything. So what's next?